# How to make this in html and css?

Tags: html, css, menu, line

I am trying to make this from a design someone gave me:

[image]

Now, I do have this:

[image]

But how am I able to add those lines on full height between the options?

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">VIP Membership</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Best Players</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Administrators</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
</ul>

#navigation { 
    float: right;
    padding-top: 8px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

#navigation li { 
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Use right and left borders. And set the line-height or the padding on the `li` instead of the parent. You really should experiment a little bit before coming here.

Comment: Yes. Additionally, it would help if you post all of your code or a jsfiddle. I can't even see the styling of your ul element here, which is pretty important, as there are a few variants to accomplish what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is **lines on full height between the options** - Answer is `border-left: 1px solid #666666`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RLjx8/)

```
#navigation
{
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #000000;
    text-align: center;
}
#navigation li
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    border-left: 1px solid #666666;
}
#navigation li:last-child
{
     border-right: 1px solid #666666;
}
#navigation li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
    font-family: arial;
}
#navigation li a:hover
{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this helped me enormously!

Comment: @user3244670 : its okay. Next time before asking questions post your relevant code or you will get too much downvotes.

Comment: I understand, this is actually my first post here, so I don't really know how everything goes here. Do you perhaps know how to add that depth line too?

Comment: @user3244670 : which line?

Comment: @user3244670 : here you go http://jsfiddle.net/RLjx8/1/ . let me know if you face any other issue..

Comment: @Beginner I mean this; http://puu.sh/6Bm2L.jpg The depth effect, is it possible, because when I try to add border-right it doesn't really do anything unfortunately.

Comment: @JM8-Real : Oh . that is very easy mate.. add **border-bottom: 3px solid red;** . Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/RLjx8/2/. change the pixel size if you want..

Comment: @Beginner haha, sorry if I was not clear, I actually meant this line |, that depth effect, sorry if I am being a pain the ass..

Comment: @JM8-Real : do you want like that? or are you facing any other issue?

Comment: @Beginner Yea, that's the way I need it, I have tried adding it but I fail to do so...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the CSS border attribute. Try something like:

```
#navigation li:not(:first-child) {
  border-left: 1px gray solid;
}
```

Comment: + hover effect that makes the text orange